# sql rowcount error despite correct syntax

Tags: sql, rollup

I have a table - t1. This table contains data about materials, amount of material in each warehouse, quality of this material, and update date (when was amount updated).

[image: initial_table]

My goal is to get summed amount of material according to its quality across all warehouses.

My first step was using ROW_NUMBER() to use only up to date information.

Result should like somehow like this:

[image: desired_result]

My syntax looks as following:

```
SELECT * FROM (
select   
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UPDATE_DATE, MATERIAL_ID, QUALITY, WAREHOUSE
 ORDER BY UPDATE_DATE desc) AS 'rownum', 
MATERIAL_ID, 
WAREHOUSE,  
 QUALITY, 
SUM(INVENTORY) as INVENTORY_TOTAL
 from t1 ) AS A
where 1=1 and rownum=1
group by rollup (MATERIAL_ID, QUALITY) 
order by MATERIAL_ID desc
```

However i get error

> Column 'A.rownum' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Before i added     `SUM(INVENTORY) as INVENTORY_TOTAL` and `group by rollup (MATERIAL_ID, QUALITY)`
everything worked fine. (in order to get the most actual data based on rownum)

Any suggestion please ?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: thanks, can i ask you, what exactly do you mean ?

Comment: . . The database has a name, such as SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, BigQuery, Postgres, and so on.  Based on the syntax, I might guess Postgres or related database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate in the *outer* query, so I think what you want is:

```
select MATERIAL_ID, QUALITY, sum(inventory)
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by MATERIAL_ID, QUALITY, WAREHOUSE order b update_date desc) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) AS A
where seqnum = 1 
group by rollup (MATERIAL_ID, QUALITY) 
order by MATERIAL_ID desc
```

Note that the `partition by` also changes.  You don't want the date in that part of the window frame specification.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your syntax works, but in results i get each material 2 times, one of these rows is correct, however second row, for example consists of material_ID=234098, quality= [NULL], quantity = 100 ... and i am unable to get rid of these NULLs despite explicitly stating that ...seqnum = 1 and quality is not null 
group by rollup .

Comment: @sqlnewbie . . . Perhaps you don't want `quality` in the `partition by`.